# Calculating point proximity in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, point, distance, zip-codes

I have a geocoded point file which (theoretically) contains one point for every zip code in the U.S. I want to create a smaller list of zip codes from this file. The list should include only those zip codes that are 100 miles from one another. In other words, if I were to look at this on a map, I would only see one point for every 100 miles, and any points in between would not be included. I'm having trouble getting this part of my project started in ArcMap 10.1. How would I go about creating this output?

I thought that I could use the Near or Point Distance tools, but I always run into trouble when trying to use the same file as both my inputs. Also, I thought that I could drape a 100x100 mile grid on top of the point file, and then grab the closest one to the center of each panel, but I'm not sure how to set that up either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I always run into trouble when trying to use the same file as both my inputs"? If the tool fails to work for whatever reason, make a copy of your input and try that. The tool is correctly working for me in 10.1.1

Comment: I do exactly that, but the file it produces tends to be extremely large, so I believe that I'm just not using the tool correctly.

Comment: Can you edit your OP to include [copy as python snippet](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/04/02/the-power-of-the-results-window/) for the tool(s) that don't seem to be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it happened, but last night someone posted that the [Integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) may be of use to me, and now their post is gone. That seems to have solved this issue! Thanks to whomever came up with that :-)